# CRTSCTS not define when compiling as C99

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, c99, termios

I'm writing some serial code on a raspberry pi and switched to C99. When I did I started getting the error "error: ‘CRTSCTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)"

```
$ c99 -M serial01.c | grep termios.h
 /usr/include/termios.h /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/termios.h \
$ gcc -M serial01.c | grep termios.h
 /usr/include/termios.h /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/termios.h \
```

using -M reveals 2 termios.h headers. the former does not contain a definition for CRTSCTS and the latter does.

I assume the standard c89 is using the good one and c99 not but I'm not sure since the result of the -M call is identical. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening when I switch to C99 and how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks Mat, fixed it with a -std=gnu99 compiler flag.

Comment: '-std=gnu99' have calped me also, you could publish it as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-std=gnu99` is the solution. More detailed below.

Result of the gcc/c99 -M call is identical but it does not mean anything! The explanation of this behavior are preprocessor macros (specifically **GNU extensions**, like said Mat).

In detail:

```
cat -n main.c
     1  #include <termios.h>
     2
     3  int printf(const char *, ...);
     4
     5  int main(void)
     6  {
     7      printf("%d\n", CRTSCTS);
     8      return 0;
     9  }
gcc main.c -o main --std=c89 -> 'CRTSCTS' undeclared compilation error
gcc main.c -o main --std=cgnu89 -> successfully compiled
```

This behavior is the same for c99 and gnu99!

Like said Cameron, -M output is identical:

```
gcc -M --std=c89 main.c | grep termios.h | nl
     1  main.o: main.c /usr/include/termios.h /usr/include/features.h \
     2   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/termios.h
gcc -M --std=gnu89 main.c | grep termios.h | nl
1  main.o: main.c /usr/include/termios.h /usr/include/features.h \
     2   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/termios.h \
```

CRTSCTS is defined in the bits/termios.h when __USE_MISC is defined

```
     1  #ifdef __USE_MISC
     2  # define CIBAUD   002003600000          /* input baud rate (not used) */
     3  # define CMSPAR   010000000000          /* mark or space (stick) parity */
     4  # define CRTSCTS  020000000000          /* flow control */
```

Let's look at __USE_MISC.

```
gcc -M /usr/include/termios.h | nl
     1  termios.o: /usr/include/termios.h /usr/include/features.h \
     2   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/predefs.h \
     3   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/cdefs.h \
     4   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/wordsize.h \
     5   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gnu/stubs.h \
     6   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/types.h \
     7   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/typesizes.h \
     8   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/termios.h \
     9   /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys/ttydefaults.h
```

First one, features.h, contains definition of __USE_MISC, but only when _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE is defined

```
grep 'define __USE_MISC' /usr/include/features.h -B 1 | nl
     1  #if defined _BSD_SOURCE || defined _SVID_SOURCE
     2  # define __USE_MISC     1
```

and _BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE is defined when _GNU_SOURCE or 'nothing' is defined

```
     1  #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
     2  # undef  _ISOC95_SOURCE
     3  # define _ISOC95_SOURCE 1
     4  # undef  _ISOC99_SOURCE
     5  # define _ISOC99_SOURCE 1
     6  # undef  _POSIX_SOURCE
     7  # define _POSIX_SOURCE  1
     8  # undef  _POSIX_C_SOURCE
     9  # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE        200809L
    10  # undef  _XOPEN_SOURCE
    11  # define _XOPEN_SOURCE  700
    12  # undef  _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED
    13  # define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
    14  # undef  _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
    15  # define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE    1
    16  # undef  _BSD_SOURCE
    17  # define _BSD_SOURCE    1
    18  # undef  _SVID_SOURCE
    19  # define _SVID_SOURCE   1
    20  # undef  _ATFILE_SOURCE
    21  # define _ATFILE_SOURCE 1
    22  #endif

    23  /* If nothing (other than _GNU_SOURCE) is defined,
    24     define _BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE.  */
    25  #if (!defined __STRICT_ANSI__ && !defined _ISOC99_SOURCE && \
    26       !defined _POSIX_SOURCE && !defined _POSIX_C_SOURCE && \
    27       !defined _XOPEN_SOURCE && !defined _BSD_SOURCE && !defined _SVID_SOURCE)
    28  # define _BSD_SOURCE    1
    29  # define _SVID_SOURCE   1
    30  #endif
```

Comment: `gnu99` is ISO C99 _with GNU extensions_. While it _may_ not cause a big issue with the Raspberry Pi, you're risking not producing portable code.

Answer (score 3):

As requested by xtreye and since the official answer does explain but doesn't actually explicitly list the solution - We both fixed this by using a `-std=gnu99` compiler flag.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -std=c99` instead of `-std=gnu99`, at least in gentoo. It "seems more standard" to me.

Searching around in `/usr/include`, I see:

```
/usr/include/features.h

 52    _DEFAULT_SOURCE  The default set of features (taking precedence over
 53       __STRICT_ANSI__).
 
 61    The `-ansi' switch to the GNU C compiler, and standards conformance
 62    options such as `-std=c99', define __STRICT_ANSI__.  If none of
 63    these are defined, or if _DEFAULT_SOURCE is defined, the default is
 64    to have _POSIX_SOURCE set to one and _POSIX_C_SOURCE set to
 65    200809L, as well as enabling miscellaneous functions from BSD and
 66    SVID.  If more than one of these are defined, they accumulate.  For
 67    example __STRICT_ANSI__, _POSIX_SOURCE and _POSIX_C_SOURCE together
 68    give you ISO C, 1003.1, and 1003.2, but nothing else.
 
383 #if defined _DEFAULT_SOURCE
384 # define __USE_MISC 1
385 #endif
```

Other files, such as in `/usr/include/boost/*` and `/usr/include/eigen3/*` also make use of `_DEFAULT_SOURCE`.

Also, the [link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) provided by @CamW in a comment is quite enlightening:

> ```
>    *  The macros that you most likely need to use in modern source
>       code are _POSIX_C_SOURCE (for definitions from various
>       versions of POSIX.1), _XOPEN_SOURCE (for definitions from
>       various versions of SUS), _GNU_SOURCE (for GNU and/or Linux
>       specific stuff), and _DEFAULT_SOURCE (to get definitions that
>       would normally be provided by default).
>
>    _DEFAULT_SOURCE (since glibc 2.19)
>           This macro can be defined to ensure that the "default"
>           definitions are provided even when the defaults would
>           otherwise be disabled, as happens when individual macros
>           are explicitly defined, or the compiler is invoked in one
>           of its "standard" modes (e.g., cc -std=c99).  Defining
>           _DEFAULT_SOURCE without defining other individual macros
>           or invoking the compiler in one of its "standard" modes
>           has no effect.
>
>           The "default" definitions comprise those required by
>           POSIX.1-2008 and ISO C99, as well as various definitions
>           originally derived from BSD and System V.  On glibc 2.19
>           and earlier, these defaults were approximately equivalent
>           to explicitly defining the following:
>
>               cc -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE
>           -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809
> ```

Comment: Interesting, based on this answer, I found https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html which explains it all quite nicely.